# gem install failing - Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby, rubygems

No matter what gem I try to install, I get

> ```
> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'watir-webdriver' (= 0.9.1), here is why:
>           Unable to download data from h ttps://rubygems.org/ - no such name (h ttps://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
> ```

I have tried a number of (rather dated) solutions on the web but they seem to be directed at trying to get past some issue. The part I find most confusing is that - as far as I can tell - the resource is accessible and does exist.  I can download `h ttps://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz` and the file is received.

What do I need to do to get this working? I'm using ruby 2.3.3 and gem 2.5.2.

Comment: `http s://` - is there really a space here? Where does it come from? Can you shor your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

there is a space in there -> `http s://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz`

if still the error, try the command:

```
gem update --system
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your network connection is not broken. 
https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3264